# Terminal command to open new Safari window

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, safari, terminal

Opening a link in Firefox from Terminal is pretty straightforward and there are many options available to the `firefox` [command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options). E.g you can do `firefox -new-window "http://stackoverflow.com"` to open the link in a new window.

I wonder if you can do the same with Safari on a Mac? `open "http://stackoverflow.com"` just opens a new Tab if there's already a window of Safari opened.
I know of apps that let you switch between "Open in new tab" and "Open in new window". Is there a special prefix to the URL to tell Safari to open a new window? Or is it just possible through Objective-C code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can place the below function with the osascript code in your .profile

code:

```
function Safari {
  # Will open a New Safari window with argument 1.

osascript <<EOD
tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:"$1"}
return
EOD

}
```

In terminal:

- cd to your home directory.
- Run : nano .profile

If you already have a .profile file it will open and there will be some code there already.

- Enter the code into it below any other code.

If you did not have one, a blank .profile file will be opened.

- Enter the code into it.

------After entering the code ----

Hold down  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press the  <kbd>x</kbd>  key.

At the bottom of the window you will be asked to save the changes.

[image]

Hit the <kbd>y</kbd> key  for yes.

You will now be asked to save it with the current name of .profile

[image]

Just hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to save it.

Run :

```
  . ~/.profile
```

This will update the environment.

now you can run:

```
Safari  "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

Note the Cap "S" in Safari.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using `vim` but thanks for your explanation anyway :-)

Answer (score 5):

This uses a different approach (osascript vs terminal) but it does what I think you are asking for:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\"
    make new document
    set URL of document 1 to \"http://www.apple.com/\"
    set bounds of window 1 to {500, 500, 800, 800}
    activate
end tell"
```